# Inheriting from a controller to perform authentication checking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a set of controllers that look like this

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
   # defines some basic authentication stuff
   # to access the control panel
end

class Admin::UploadController < AdminController
  # require authentication to access this page
end
```

The admin controller is where I wish to define all of my authentication functionality. There are a number of controllers that also require authentication, so I figured I might as well just inherit the same authentication code from the existing admin controller.

Are there any problems with this approach that I might need to know about?

Comment: inheritance will be a good approach for that. For an other approach, you can define your methods in as helper methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so.

If you use before_filter to authenticate in AdminController and user inherit in every controller it will run this filter.